# Swapping list of binary numbers, but only of x length

Tags: python

I'm having difficulties simplifying a script. What I have currently generates a list of arrays with all possible combinations (given the number of digits in the binary string), eliminates the lists where their combined value exceeds the number of digits I need swapped, and then generates a list of their absolute subtracted values.

For example:

If I supply '101' It would create list:
`[1,0,1]`

It would then ask how many I want swapped.
If I say '2'

It would take the length of the original list(3), and generate all possible binary combinations for that length: 
`([0,0,0][1,0,0][0,1,0][0,0,1][1,1,0][1,0,1][0,1,1][1,1,1])`

It would then eliminate those where the combined values does not equal '2':
`([1,1,0][1,0,1][0,1,1])`
,subtract their values from the original list, taking the absolute value, giving me:
`([0,1,1][0,0,0][1,1,0])`

Now this is... fine if I'm sticking with small values of fixed length, but I  am working with binary numbers of different lengths, and different number of values I need swapped (up to 500, which would take more than my life to generate). I've seen some of the amazingly elegant and simple solutions some of the users here have come up with, and was hoping someone would be able to help me simplify this one to a few lines of code.

Comment: The asker explains what they've already tried in the first few paragraphs of their post. I don't think they need to be admonished for this question.

Comment: OT. Sounds like a homework question to me.

Comment: @StefanBecker homework questions are [specifically allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as long as they _"include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_ - which this question does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.combinations` is particularly handy here - we can tell it to give us combinations of N indices to flip, and then flip each of those in turn.

Here's an example using `itertools` and a generator function:

```
import itertools

def n_indices_flipped(sequence, n):
  for indices_to_flip in itertools.combinations(range(len(sequence)), n):
    item = sequence[:]
    for index in indices_to_flip:
      # flip 0 to 1 or vice versa
      item[index] = 1 - item[index]
    yield item

# Usage:
all_flipped_variants = list(n_flipped([1, 0, 1], 2))
print(all_flipped_variants)
# prints [[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you, Amber. This is perfect, and exactly what I was looking for. Much simpler than the literal code I was using. I had come across itertools in the past, but never really looked into it. Looks like I have more studying to do :)

Comment: Note that for larger sequences, and larger numbers of flips, this will still begin to slow down very quickly - that's simply because the number of n-pick-k combinations grows quite quickly - `n! / (k! * (n-k)!)` in fact. So it'll never be fast for truly larger numbers. But hopefully this should be slightly more efficient in the mid range.

Comment: Tell me about it lol I've had to sequester a separate machine just for generating these lists. Currently looking at around 30GB worth . Should take a month or so once all is said and done.

Comment: @Amber - nice solution